# Android Spinner using Arraylist not working

Tags: android, arraylist, android-spinner

**CityBeans.java**
this is my bean used in `cityArrayList`

```
public class CityBeans implements Serializable {
        private int ;
        private String name;
        public int getId() {
                return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
                this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
                return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
                this.name = name;
        }
```

**Home.java**

```
 public class Home extends BaseActivity {

          private ProgressDialog dialog;
          private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
          private TextView tap1, tap2;
          private String cityUrl ="http://arabnewtech.org/zoodre/public/api/locations/city/3";
          private Spinner citySpinner;
          private ArrayList<CityBeans> cityBeansList;

           @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (WrapContentViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    // Create Tabs Handelation
    tabsHandel();

    // Initialize Views
    initViews();

    // City Spinner
    getCityData();


    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client2 = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
}

        public void getCityData() {

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(Home.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Waiting ....");
        dialog.show();

        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        client.get(cityUrl, params, new TextHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
                //Log.d("---Error---", responseString);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                Log.d("---result---", responseString);
                try {
                    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(responseString);
                    JSONArray jo_result = jo.getJSONArray("result");
                    cityBeansList = new ArrayList<CityBeans>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < jo_result.length(); i++) {

                        CityBeans cityBean = new CityBeans();

                        JSONObject my_jo = jo_result.getJSONObject(i);
                        cityBean.setId(my_jo.getInt("id"));
                        cityBean.setName(my_jo.getString("name"));
                        cityBeansList.add(cityBean);
                    }

                    ArrayAdapter<CityBeans> adapter;
                    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CityBeans>(Home.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cityBeansList);
                    //adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    citySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.i("---Result Error","Here We found error");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
      }
```

**Fragment.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.arabnewtech.a22.zoodrealstate.Home$PlaceholderFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/spinner1">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/cityID"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"></Spinner>

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Spinner>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_below="@id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"></Spinner>

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Spinner>
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/ColorYellow"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner2"
        android:text="بحث"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: where is the `onCreate()` method in your activity

Comment: You have to create custom Adapter for it.

Comment: you have to create custom adapter because you are getting spinner values from web services

Comment: like this<http://androidexample.com/Custom_Spinner_With_Image_And_Text_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=84>

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example.
This layout created for spinner design. I stored id, and name like you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtApplyID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtApplyName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

like your City Beans.

```
public class Apply
{
        private String _id;
        private String _name;

        public Apply(String id, String name)
        {
            this._id = id;
            this._name = name;
        }

        public String GetID()
        {
            return this._id;
        }

        public String GetName()
        {
            return this._name;
        }
}
```

custom `ApplyAdapter` for spinner

```
public class ApplyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
        private List<Apply> applyList;

        public ApplyAdapter(Activity activity, List<Apply> applyList)
        {
            this.layoutInflater =    (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            this.applyList = applyList;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return this.applyList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return this.applyList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View viewerino;
            viewerino = this.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_apply_item, null);
  //my layout file spinner_apply_item you have to create.
            TextView id = (TextView)viewerino.findViewById(R.id.txtApplyID);
            TextView name = (TextView)viewerino.findViewById(R.id.txtApplyName);
            Apply apply = this.applyList.get(position);
            id.setText(apply.GetID());
            name.setText(apply.GetName());
            return viewerino;
        }
    }
```

and call it in your activity.

```
ApplyAdapter applyAdapter = new ApplyAdapter(MainActivity.this,this.applyList);
this.spnApply.setAdapter(applyAdapter);
```

there is a part of my activity layout.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.volkan.dkbilisim.MainActivity">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainRltHeader"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/relative_design"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            >

             <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/mainSpinner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                ></Spinner>

</RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why you don`t use Spinner in your xml ?

Comment: It's a not spinner. just wait i'll edit. Spinner has to be in activity layout.

Comment: You have to create a layout file for spinner, you cant use it array list for your CityBeans class. You have to create custom adapter. Try this it will work.